# Has a woman in a Hallmark movie ever chosen her boyfriend from the city over her boyfriend from the country?

Tags: ending, drama, romance

I am curious to know if there ever was a Hallmark movie in which the woman ended up choosing her boyfriend from the city over her boyfriend from the country. This would mean that towards the end of the movie, she first says goodbye to her boyfriend from the country and then goes back to the city with her boyfriend from the city and it appears that they will live happily ever after.

Has a woman in a Hallmark movie ever chosen her boyfriend from the city over her boyfriend from the country?